# How to generate reports in android based on user input

Tags: android, jasper-reports, reporting

How can I build an android app which basically get the inputs from user and output as a **graphs and bar charts** used for analysis. Is there any built in components for reporting or can Jasper reports be integrated to to solve this kind of approach? Please suggest me.

Here is the similar question , but didnt get correct clue. 
     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969948/generate-reports-in-android
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need any charting feature in your Android projects, you might
want to consider using the AChartEngine framework. It currently
supports the following chart types:

- line chart
- area chart
- scatter chart
- time chart
- bar chart
- pie chart

The above supported chart types can contain multiple series, can have
the X axis rendered horizontally (default) or vertically and support a
high level of customization. Any chart can be built as a view that can
be added to a view group or as an intent for starting an activity.

Instructions on how to download and import a demo project with source
code included can be found here: 
http://www.achartengine.org/content/goodies.html

[This is a sample tutorial to create graphs](https://sites.google.com/site/androidhowto/how-to-1/create-graphs)